# panel won't open and pageinit won't fire

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to open a jquery mobile panel through code but the method is not recognized.

the error I'm getting is: "Object[object Object} has no method 'panel' "

I have a html page consists of several jquery-mobile div pages and an external javascript file.

**this is the js function:**

```
function open_panel() {

    var selected_child=$('#kids_select').val();
    alert(selected_child);

    $("#mypanel").panel("open");
      //    $("#mypanel").panel().panel("open");




}

$('#mypanel').live('pageinit', function () {
    alert("works");
});
```

I'ts a project started by another student, and he included duplicate js files in the html head section. I guess it's because the old jquery mobile is loaded insted of the 1.3, but when I try to remove some of the references the design gets all messy or some other code isn't recognized.

**here's the head section:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.core.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.calbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/i18n/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.en_US.utf8.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">
    </script>

    <script src="js/js_functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

finnaly I added a href attribute to the 'a' tag pointing the panel and it gets loaded after the function fires up, but the panel's pageinit function won't fire.

**I tried:**

```
$('#mypanel').live('pageinit', function () {
    alert("works");
});
```

**and:**

```
 $('#mypanel').live('pageshow', function () {
        alert("works");
    });
```

but that doesn't work

**here's the relevant part of the html body: (with the panel)**

```
 <div data-role="page" id="mainpage">

            <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
                <h3>
                    Iallow
                </h3>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content" style="text-align: center;">
                <div>

                    <div style="width: 50%; float: left">
                        <label for="NewkidBTN">
                            Click to add new kid</label>
                        <a id="NewkidBTN" data-role="button" data-theme="b" href="#RegisterChild" data-icon="plus"
                            data-iconpos="right">Add Kid</a>
                    </div>

                    <div id="kids_div">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <a onclick="open_panel()" href="#mypanel" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="bars">Add transaction</a>


            </div>

            <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel">
                    <h3>enter action</h3>
                    <select name="select-type" id="select-type" onclick="return select-type_onclick()">
                        <option value="deposit">deposit</option>
                        <option value="withdrawal">withdrawal</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="ammount">Write the ammount</label>
                    <input type="number" data-clear-btn="false" name="ammount" id="ammount" value="">
                    <label for="desc" class="ui-hidden-accessible">
                        description:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="desc" id="descTB" value="" placeholder="description" runat="server" />
                    <button id="Button1" type="submit" data-theme="b" data-icon="check" runat="server" onclick="transaction">
                        submit</button>
                </div>
```

**edit:**

I changed the head section by removing old jquery mobile and jquery.
now the panel loads but the pageinit function I added to the panel won't fire up.
I tried every syntax, such as:

```
$('#mypanel').live('pageshow', function () {
    alert("works");
});

$('#mypanel').live('pageinit', function () {
    alert("works");

$('#mypanel').on('pageshow', function () {
    alert("works");
});

$('#mypanel').on('pageinit', function () {
    alert("works");
});
```

maybe panels don't work like pages in jquery mobile..

the head now looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css" />-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.min.css" />
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.core.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.calbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/i18n/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.en_US.utf8.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <title></title>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />-->

    <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>-->
    <!--<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">
    </script>-->

    <script src="js/js_functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: first you need to remove old jquery and jquery mobile. instead of `.live` use `.on`.

Comment: thank you for your comment. can you please see my edit? I removed the old versions and the panel loads. but the pageinit/pageshow function won't fire up. (all functions are in external js file)